# Get output record partition within Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KStream which branches and writes output records into different topics based on some internal logic. Is there any way I can know the partition of the output message from inside the KStream? The output topics have different number of partitions from the input ones.

Comment: IIRC, input and output topics need matching partition counts (or maybe thats only for joins). What do you plan on doing with the partition number?

Answer (score 0):

When using the high-level DSL, you don't have access to the record metadata (which holds a key/value pair on specific partition the record came from). So you won't be able to achieve the goal using KStream implementation.

You could use the low-level processor API if you wanted, which would allow access to the metadata. Otherwise, you can add an implementation of ConsumerInterceptor, and map the partition value to the message before it goes to the consumer.